# Datadog event using micrometer

Tags: metrics, datadog, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I am utilizing [DogStatsD](https://docs.datadoghq.com/developers/dogstatsd/?tab=hostagent) approach to send metrics to datadog using micrometer. I get the normal metrics like counter and gauge but I am not able to generate events. Is there a way to generate datadog events?

Comment: did you find solution

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it is not possible at the Moment to use micrometer to send events to datadog. Micrometer states that *"Micrometer is not a distributed tracing system or an event logger.*" on its section "1. Purpose" on its [concepts page](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts).

Answer (score 0):

There is now built-in support for micrometer integration since sprint boot 2.0: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-metrics